# How to make japanese character font (Ipaex gothic / mincho) bold?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've installed the `IPAex Gothic` and `IPAex Mincho` fonts and can display Japanese characters. I'm trying to display some Japanese characters in bold.

Now I want to display some of those characters in bold, but I'm failing at that.

I've tried several options with no success:

```
    <span style="font-size: 26px; font-family: IPAexGothic, IPAexMincho; font-weight:800;">
    日本
    </span>
  
    <span style="font-size: 26px; font-family: IPAexGothic, IPAexMincho; font-weight:bold;">
    日本
    </span>

    <span style="font-size: 26px; font-family: IPAexGothic, IPAexMincho;">
    <strong>日本</strong>
    </span>
```

Any idea on how to get those Japanese characters displayed in bold?

Comment: Do those font families even include a bold variant?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't think so. I haven't found any on Google.

Comment: Did you try <b><b/>?

Comment: So if there is no bold variant for that font, there is no way to make it bold with any CSS "trick"?

Comment: @deechris27 yes, I've tried that, thanks. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If the font does not have any bold variant, you can't make it **bold**.

But... you can fake a bold font (if that's what you need to do, it's not a clean approach).
Some things to play around with are borders and text-shadow, for example:

`.outlined { color: white; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000 };`